# Grabbing arguments of a variadic function in iOS x64

Tags: ios, objective-c, arm, variadic, arm64

being very straight, in x86 builds I can do this:

```
static id method(id)(id self, SEL _cmd, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, _cmd);
```

args as you know will contain a pointer to the stack and by making:
    args += size(type);

I could iterate through the full list of args.

Keeping it short, args will contain a list with pointers to my arguments.

I want this to work in ios X64 device but it is not working as expected,

```
va_list args;
va_start(args, _cmd);
```

does not returns a pointer to the top of the stack containing the arguments anymore =/

How can I grab a list of pointers to the arguments in ios arm64 like I did in ios armv7/7s?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your post is lacking some details about your implementation that would help others assist you. If you can provide a short *complete* code snippet that exhibits the erroneous behaviour, describe your input, result, and expected result, someone will have a better chance to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not stdarg/variadic calls return any kind of a stack indication is implementation dependent and should not be relied on (e.g. a particular abi/compiler implementation may not have a stack on which to place arguments).  What is guaranteed is that you can use it in a standard fashion to evaluate the unnamed arguments to the function:

```
static id method(id)(id self, SEL _cmd, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, _cmd);

    const char* pointerArg = va_arg(args, const char *);
    int arg = va_arg(args, int);

    va_end(args);
}
```

Each invocation of va_arg returns an argument of the appropriate type and moves args to reference the next argument.

For more information, you can check out the [stdarg.h wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h)

Comment: True, Fixed.  And more fluff so it will accept the comment.

Comment: va_arg is not working on x64 apple arch variadic function calls, I already tried it, it is returning bad pointers for me =/

Comment: Odds are good that you're using it incorrectly then. Edit your question to add the actual routine and an invocation of it.